# Discord.js Unban command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I got a unban command code, and I get the following error in the console:

> (node:9348) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\commands\unban.js:9:22)
> at Client. (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\gb.js:81:17)
> at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\19nik\Documents\GitHub\bot-project\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)

This is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    name: `unban`,
    description: `Unbans given user ID or mentioned user.`,
    async execute(bot, args, message) {

        if (!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide me a valid USER ID.");
        //This if() checks if we typed anything after "!unban"

        let bannedMember;
        //This try...catch solves the problem with the await
        try {
            bannedMember = await bot.users.cache.fetch(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            if (!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("That's not a valid USER ID.")
        }

        //Check if the user is not banned
        try {
            await message.guild.fetchBan(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send('This user is not banned.');
            return;
        }

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided."

        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("I am missing permissions to unban.")
        message.delete()
        try {
            message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason })
            message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned.`)
            console.log(`AUDIT LOG: [UNBAN] ${message.author.tag} unbanned ${member.user.tag} from ${message.guild.name}.`);
            var readmessagefile = fs.readFileSync('./logging/UnbanLog.txt', 'utf-8');
            var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync('./logging/UnbanLog.txt', 'Type: [UNBAN] ' + 'Time ' + '(' + message.createdAt + ')' + ' | ' + member.user.tag + ' from ' + message.guild.name + ' | Moderator ' + message.author.tag + '\n' + readmessagefile)
            console.log('BOT LOG: [INTERNAL] Writing to unban log file.');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do. It also pops up a error of cannot read property 'hasPermissions' of undefined too.

Comment: It seems `message` is undefined. Have you checked its value?

Comment: i have put message on the async execute(). do i have to put it somewhere else

Comment: You should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65704184/edit) and add how you call the `.execute()` function.

Comment: i indeed do have included the async execute() included. But, no worries. Someone gave me a fix and got a different problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will work.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    name: `unban`,
    description: `Unbans given user ID or mentioned user.`,
    async execute(bot, args, message) {
        if(!message.guild) return message.channel.send("This Command Can't Be Executed In DMs.");
        if (!message.author.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide me a valid USER ID.");
        //This if() checks if we typed anything after "!unban"

        let bannedMember;
        //This try...catch solves the problem with the await
        try {
            bannedMember = await bot.users.cache.fetch(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            if (!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("That's not a valid USER ID.")
        }

        //Check if the user is not banned
        try {
            await message.guild.fetchBan(args[0])
        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send('This user is not banned.');
            return;
        }

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided."

        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("I am missing permissions to unban.")
        message.delete()
        try {
            message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason })
            message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned.`)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the console logging section cause it might start occurring some errors.

It might be wrong cause i am newbie

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main source of your problem is your callback, having called your `client` first before `message` and `args`.
Since JS is sensitive for callback parameter placement, you should instead write your callback as the following:

```
async execute(message, args, bot)
```

Comment: will try this now.

Comment: that fixed it the cannot read errors, but i got a new issue now. I use a user ID that has been banned in the server but, bot gives back in the chat the following message of please provide a valid USER ID.

Answer (score 0):

There error seems to be at line 9

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("You do not have the required permissions to use the unban command.")
```

Which doesn't have an error, maybe the command was ran in DMS? Maybe use:

```
if(!message.guild) return;
```

Which should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons :

**Callback**

make sure the parameters of execute() are in the exact order as in your main file

**Command is used outside a guild**

The error might have happened because the command was using outside a guild to fix this add this to your code below execute()

```
if (!message.guild) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const findUser = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
if(!findUSer) return;
const isMemberHavePermission = findUser.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")
iF(isMemberHavePermission){
  // Member Have Permission
 }else{
  // Member Have not Permission
 }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're using discord.js v12, also make sure you're in the latest (or v14) version of node.js, if not at least in v14, download at https://node.js.org

This is from my bot, try this, it works, and I've changed it to your handler:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")

module.exports = {
  name: "unban",
  description: "Unbans given user ID or mentioned user.",
  async execute(bot, message, args) {
    
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send(`You need the permission **Ban Members** to execute this command.`)
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send(`**${client.user.tag}** needs the permission **Ban Members** to execute this command.`)
    
    const id = args[0];
    
    if (!id) return message.channel.send(`Please mention the user's ID to unban.`)

const bannedMember = client.users.fetch(args[0]);    

    const bans = await message.guild.fetchBans();
    if (bans.size == 0) return message.channel.send(`There are no users banned on this server.`);
    let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == id);
    if(!bUser) return message.channel.send(`This user is not banned or was not found.`)

      const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
      if (!reason) return message.channel.send('Please include a reason!');

    try {
                    message.guild.members.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason })
            message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned.`)
            console.log(`AUDIT LOG: [UNBAN] ${message.author.tag} unbanned ${member.user.tag} from ${message.guild.name}.`);
            var readmessagefile = fs.readFileSync('./logging/UnbanLog.txt', 'utf-8');
            var writemessagefile = fs.writeFileSync('./logging/UnbanLog.txt', 'Type: [UNBAN] ' + 'Time ' + '(' + message.createdAt + ')' + ' | ' + member.user.tag + ' from ' + message.guild.name + ' | Moderator ' + message.author.tag + '\n' + readmessagefile)
            console.log('BOT LOG: [INTERNAL] Writing to unban log file.');

     } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
}
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment since I don't have 50 reputation, but you should use `message.member.permissions.has(...)` instead of `message.member.hasPermission(...)`